# Latest version of Fuelux - I can't get datepicker working in wizard - next button

Tags: fuelux

background:

Quite easily I've got the Fuelux Wizard working.
I now wanted to introduce a date picker in one of the steps.
I did get the datepicker working fine outside of the wizard.

my problem:

when I introduced it into the form i have had problems.
The next and previous buttons do work but the page is immediately reloaded.

I debugged through the code and I see that the calendar is updated but then
the jquery event handling code returns and then my page is reloaded.

I'm at a loss to understand why the page is being reloaded.

I'm guessing that it is something to do with the event handling in the wizard
- as this html code works perfeclty outside of the wizard.

Any ideas ?

Has anybody got this working ?

Comment: I changed to use a jquery datepicker and it worked fine in the Fuelux wizard.  I believe that there is an issue (due to events) with using the Fuelux datepicker and the Fuelux wizard together.

Comment: Do all your buttons use `type="button"` attribute? Otherwise, any buttons within a form will reload the page, because they will default to submit.

Comment: I suppose the datapicker prev and next buttons must call submit then and cause the form to reload... that might be the problem indeed. Is there way to stop this ? (and I can check if that is the issue)

Comment: The way to stop it is to use `type="button"` in your markup.